# SSIS - package works in VS, fails with "Failed to compiled scripts contained in the package". There are no script objects in the package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2016, ssis-2016

VS2017, Deploy to SS2016. Package runs without any errors from VS. Project deployment to a server that previously had package deployments only - we're moving to project deployment, and DBAs said to use that.

Getting many errors like:

> Get Error Information:Error: Failed to compiled scripts contained in the package. Open the package in SSIS Designer and resolve the compilation errors.

The package has absolutely no script objects. I've checked with the package explorer, and there isn't even a scripts section. To verify, I added an empty script, and then the explorer did show that section.

Other info: Package deployment is new to our DBAs. They are completely mystified by this, and other errors, like:

> Get Error Information:Error: CS2001 - Source file 'C:\Windows\TEMP.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs' could not be found, CSC, 0, 0

My opinion, unexpert in SSIS as I am, is that these servers are not set up or configured properly in some way, but I am out of my depth in this, and DBAs are floundering. What might I do to get to the root of this?

Comment: Please note that "Failed to compiled", as incorrect as that is grammatically, is literally what the messages say.

Comment: You're deploying from SSDT correct?  Do you get the same error when deploying via the SSIS Deployment Wizard?

Comment: is .Net framework and ssdt installed correctly on the deployment server?

Comment: Are you sure you have looked at all possible spots within the package? What about the event handlers?

Comment: We have had the same problem deploying from VS 2017 to SQL Server 2014 when the packages contain scripts. I'm pretty sure it's a bug/deficiency in Visual Studio because it seems to be a problem with corruption of the scripts when VS upgrades the package. The only workaround we've found is to use old versions of VS for deployment. :(

Comment: I was advised by our Sr DBA not to use VS2017. She found 2016 more friendly to VS.

Comment: @rvphx Yes. In fact, the scripts section of the explorer is empty. To test it, I added a script, which then appeared as the only one in the explorer.

Comment: @userfl89 I've only deployed from VS2016.

Comment: I see this exact error (and wrong grammar !) in our production server too. SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 2):

I ended up side-stepping the issue by essentially recreating the package. Even XML search revealed no scripts, so the assumption was some kind of corruption. The package was recently upgraded to package-deployment - perhaps that action had a hand in the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For me this was happening because I was targeting the wrong database version. in your SSIS Package project go into properties and set the TargetServerVersion appropriately And then recompile the project and redeploy to sql server.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue and isolated the problem to a Script Task (regardless of language) that existed in a Sequence Container. Placing the Script Task outside the Sequence Container, and upgrading the package to 2016 worked. The package was originally 2012 (as far as I can see) and the server side SSIS was 2016 13.2.5426.0. We were using VS 2017 as well.